# Glue at bottom of page

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, page-breaking

I'm writing a lengthy document which will have prompts typically between 2 and 5 lines  long with a space after each prompt for notes.  Ideally I want a 2-inch space with a stretch of 1 in and a shrink of 0.2 in.  The 'internal' prompts are easily handled with `\vspace{2in plus 1in minus 0.2in}`.

The problem is at the bottom of the page, since TeX absorbs glue at the bottom of pages.  I've tried variations of `\vspace`, `\filbreak`, and `\def\filbreak{\par\vfil\penalty-200\vfilneg}`, adjusting both the `\vfil` and `\vfilneg`.  No success.  Either the bottom prompt's space is the normal 2 in and the rest are spaced evenly using the remaining space or the bottom space is whatever's left on the page after the others are set to 2 in.

Is there any way to (automatically) evenly distribute the spaces?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=1in]{geometry}

%\def\spacer{
%    \par\vspace*{1.7in plus 0.5in minus 0.3in} \penalty-200 % 
%    \vfilneg}
\def\comment{The page total is \the\pagetotal. \spacer}
\def\spacer{\par\vspace{2.4in plus 1in minus 0.2in} \penalty-200}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document} 

\comment

\comment

\comment

\comment

...

\comment

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you make the glue more stretchy it should more closely balance the glue added at the bottom of the page.  Try `\vspace{2.4in plus 1fill minus 0.2in}` in your macro.  Does that give you what you want?

Comment: `\par\nopagebreak\vspace{2in plus 1in minus 0.2in}`?

Comment: @Thruston: That totally did it.  I had previously tried `\vspace{2in plus 1fil minus 0.2in}`.  I guess I just needed more infinity.  @egreg: Yours still leaves larger gaps at the bottom of the pages.

Answer (score 3):

Try making the glue more infinitely stretchy so that it balances the glue added by the page eject (which is essentially equal to `\vfill\eject`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=1in]{geometry}

%\def\spacer{
%    \par\vspace*{1.7in plus 0.5in minus 0.3in} \penalty-200 % 
%    \vfilneg}
\def\comment{The page total is \the\pagetotal. \spacer}
\def\spacer{\par\vspace{2.4in plus 1fill minus 0.2in} \penalty-200}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document} 

\comment

\comment

\comment

\comment

...

\comment

\end{document}
```